# PHPExcel erro gerar o Excel usando Fórmula CONT.SES com o sinal =

Tags: php, phpexcel

Boa tarde,

Fiz uma implementação para gerar uma planilha excel onde em uma célula deverá ser inserida a fórmula CONT.SES(). Porém se eu colocar o sinal de igual (=) antes do CONT.SES() -> =CONT.SES é lançado a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> B4 -> Formula Error: An unexpected error occured

Só funciona se não tiver o sinal de = antes do CONT.SES.

Alguém saberia me dizer como resolver isso?

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Mas o CONT.SES() precisa dos parametros, senão retorna erro, precisa do intervalo e do comparador: =CONT.SES(intervalo;"=AlgumaCoisa")

Comment: Sim, possui todos os parâmetros lá no código, coloquei aqui sem os parâmetros CONT.SES() só para simplificar.... O erro é lançado se tiver o sinal de = antes, sem o sinal de igual funciona perfeitamente.